# Predicting class probabilities in regression based on area under the curve

Tags: regression, predictive-models, prediction, auc

Logistic regression models the log odds. That is for rv $Y$ which is binary

logit$(Y=1)=X\beta$.

Then with this model, you can estimate the class probabilities and hence prediction or classification is immediate. Ordinal regression does a similar thing with cumulative logits with which the class probabilities can then be calculated. Now looking at $AUC$ regression where Dodd and Peppe(2003) modeled the $AUC$, by

$AUC$=$P(Y<Y^{\prime}$ $|$ $X,X^{\prime}$)=$f(X\beta)$ where $X$ are covariates. My question is how do we now do predictions with such a model.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression models the probability of a binary response. We use some sigmoidal function to predict a value that lies between 0 and 1.

The logit function is just one popular link function. Why? It goes between zero and one. Probit is another link function. $\Phi(X\beta)$ uses the cumulative distribution function of a normal to do the same job as logit.

AUC is another function(al?) that goes between zero and one. You could also look at it as a variable between 0 and 1 that is to be predicted. Having had a look at the [paper](http://works.bepress.com/margaret_pepe/19/) you mentioned I think they are using logistic regression to model the AUC, e.g. from the following quote:

> When the logit link is used, exponentiated parameters have interpretations as AUC odds, where AUC odds are defined as [...]

Comment: Thanks @conjecture for your attention.With logistic regression( irrespective of the link function) you will make statements like for a given patient with characteristics $X_i$  the probability of belonging to class 1 (without loss of generality) is for example 0.61. Similar statements can be made with cumulative  models. With the $AUC$ model you can only say for subject $i$ with characteristics $X_i$ the $AUC$ for that patient is say 0.71. You can't say anything further, you can't say that that patient will be classified to class 0 with a certain probability can you?

Comment: You can't make such a statement because there is no one to one relationship between $ROC$ and $AUC$. If such a relationship existed, we would have produced a $ROC$ for each subject and with that $ROC$ make suitable cut-offs and then based on that cut-off we can say this patient will belong to class 1 with sensitivity say 0.81. That will be a nice prediction model. So I will like to know if there is indeed some way we can make a one to one $AUC$ and $ROC$  relationship.

Comment: Using ROC to find cut-offs this way is at odds with optimum decisions.  Why you would not want to use the gold standard of maximum likelihood estimation is completely unclear.

Comment: @Frank thanks I caught your attention. I have modeled the $AUC$ and  with same model, given the optimum decision. I will like to go ahead to make predictions. I do not get your point of $ML$ estimation. Dodd and Peppe(2003) parameter estimates were $ML$ estimates.

Comment: AUC does not relate to optimum decisions.  Optimum decisions use the predicted risk and a loss/utility/cost function.  If you do not have a utility function (which is external to the data and comes from preferences etc.) then the goal should be to accurately estimate the risk (probability) which is precisely what maximum likelihood estimation can do.

Comment: Thanks once again for your comment. Since I cannot edit my last comment, I will clarify it. Indeed I meant given the the cost function and you have a model such as that of Dodd and Pepe(2003) which only models the $AUC$. **I will like to use the same model for prediction**. I know I am stating the problem in a complete opposite direction. Why go from $AUC$ then to predicted classes?. Meanwhile the natural way is to go from the predicted classes then the $ROC$ and with a defined cost function pickup an optimal decision rule.

Comment: What you are doing is at odds with optimum prediction, and an unnecessary complication.  Straight maximum likelihood estimation using the good old-fashioned logistic model will accomplish you goal straightforwardly.

Answer (score 1):

You make predictions in exactly the same way as in the ordinary model. AUC is a summary of how well the model separates the two classes (similar to how $R^2$ is a summary of the model's improvement in explained variance compared to the mean of the response), but has no bearing on the task of predicting class membership $\hat{y}$ given some covariates $X$.